# Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array in a simple CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

This is a very simple problem that I cannot get around. I am new to tensorflow and this is the second time I am facing this problem.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np


x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128, 128, 4))
conv = Conv2D(30, (3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(128, 128, 4))(x)
conv = Conv2D(12, (5,5))(conv)
conv = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv)
print(conv[2])
conv = np.array(conv[2]) # <---- here is the problem
input_mean = np.mean(conv[1:], axis=0)
input_std = np.std(conv, axis=0)
conv = (conv - input_mean) / input_std

conv = Flatten()(conv)
conv = Dense(157, activation='relu')(conv)
model = Model(inputs = x, outputs = conv)
#model.summary()
```

The error that I am getting is,

```
Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.
```

My question is, How would I take the **Output** from my **Maxpooling** layer and take the mean and standard deviation for each incoming channel? The output of the mean and std would be a tensor where each channel is separately normalized. I would then flatten this output and send it to my fully connected dense layer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I obtained a similar error and I performed the following:

```
del model
```

Before:

```
model = Model(inputs = x, outputs = conv)
```

It resolved my issue.
I am eager to know if it solves your issue too:) .